# In VB.net websites, VS2008 ALWAYS uses space indentation for new files

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, tabs

So, I've changed my settings in Tools | Options | Text Editor, for All Languages, Basic, **and** C#, to having Block indenting, and 'Keep tabs'.  I've also tried this with Smart indenting too.  Now, although once I start editing a file, its auto indentation is done with tabs, when I create a new web form in my ASP.net website, VS2008 *insists* on creating the initial code with space indentation.  So for example, I'll get an aspx.vb file for my new page like so:

```
Partial Class Admin_Index
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

End Class
```

Note that the 'Inherits' line is SPACE-indented, **even though** I have the text editor settings set to keep tabs.  Is there any way I can make the default created files indented with tabs, not spaces?  Or is VS just too stubborn?  :-)

By the way, please don't just respond and say this is petty as I can quickly change that one line of indentation to using a tab.  I know this, but I have a software team that find it irritating as we have an SVN hook that prevents checkins if there's any space-indentation.  It would be very useful if any newly-created files have tab indentation from the start, rather than us having to change it every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If none of the Visual Studio settings work, you could change the template files to have tabs in them. They're found in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VisualBasic\`, in zip files.

Also, you can quickly re-format the currently opened file by pressing `Ctrl+K`, `Ctrl+D` (Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document).